# Fail on install sql 2017

Tags: sql-server

I tried to install SQL server 2017 on my win 10 desk and got this error:

> KB2919355 Check Failed. If you have installed KB2919355, please make
>   sure you have restarted your machine. For more information, you can
>   visit https://support.microsoft.com/kb/2919355/

I searched and all solution I founded is download and install update kb2919355, but it for win 8 or server 2012 not for WIN 10. So what I should try?

Comment: Have you restarted, as it suggests?

Comment: Also, by any chance, did your PC used to have Windows 8/8.1 installed and you upgraded to Windows 10?

Comment: @Larnu: no, I install win 10 from beginning. And kb2919355 not work with win 10

Comment: If you haven't restarted then i suggest you do, as it suggests.

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: Install patch [KB2919442](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=42153)

Step 1: Install patch [KB2919355.](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=42334)

Note that KB2919355 is not a single patch but a package of KBs which, as provided in Microsoft’s instructions, need to be installed in the following order:

– clearcompressionflag.exe
– KB2919355
– KB2932046
– KB2959977
– KB2937592
– KB2938439
– KB2934018

install all this and restart will be done!